# jquery sortable - fields automatically populate when certain fields selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a basic sortable list

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">        
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="1">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="2">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="3>3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="a">a</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="b">b</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="c">c</li>
</ul>

    <div id="sortedFields">
        <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable"></ul>
    </div>
```

which works fine. What I'd like to do, but have no idea how, is to have some fields dependant on others. So, if I drag field "1" over to "sortable2", then field "a" automatically gets placed in "sortable2". If I drag "2" over, "b" automatically gets placed in "sortable2".

Pretty new to this so not sure if this is possible, or if this is something that's super easy. Have been looking on the [sortable site](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) but nothing has popped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am just the delivery person of this answer, and did not solve it.

I WANTED to solve it, but then I found that someone had not only solved it, but included a little gold plating as well (you can drag/drop/sort into new `<ul>'s` as well).

Here's the code, found from this S.O. thread: [Make draggable element sortable within droppable using jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986157/make-draggable-element-sortable-within-droppable-using-jquery-ui)

HTML:

```
<ul id="pool" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>foo1</li>
    <li>foo2</li>
    <li>foo3</li>
</ul>

<hr>

<ul class="connectedSortable new"></ul>

<ul class="connectedSortable new hidden"></ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    initSort($('.connectedSortable'));
});

function initSort(element) {
    element.sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
            var parent = ui.helper.parent();
            if(parent.hasClass('new')) {
                parent.removeClass('new');
                var clone = $('.connectedSortable.new.hidden').clone();
                clone.insertAfter(parent).removeClass('hidden');
                initSort($('.connectedSortable'));
            }
            cleanUp();
        }
    }).disableSelection();
}

function cleanUp() {
    $('.connectedSortable').not('.new, #pool').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('li').length == 0) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
ul { list-style: none; }
li { cursor: pointer; }

.connectedSortable {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

.connectedSortable.new { border: 1px dashed; }

.hidden { display: none; }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DKBU9/12/)

Comment: Hi, not sure if I'm missing something, but I don't see how this does what I asked? Like, for that fiddle you linked, no field is dependent on another. What I need to be able to do is if I were to click and drag "foo1" down, then "foo3" would automatically be placed where "foo1" is.

Comment: Well, I started screwing around with that JSFiddle you linked and I came up with something that appears to work: https://jsfiddle.net/rngv2fow/3/ . Not sure if it's the best way of going about it, but it appears to do what I want. Thanks for the link